# ORA-00936: falta una expresión

Tags: sql, oracle

I am executing the following query in Oracle that I have made in Postgres:

```sql
with FILTRADO_INICIAL as (
select *
  from SUREM.tabs_values tv
 where tv.affected = 1
   and tv.incidents = 1
   and tv.tab = 12 
),
LAST_DATA as (
select case
         when idrow is null THEN row_number() over (partition by affected, incidents, field, owner order by insert_date desc)
         else 1
       end as counter_field,
       case
         when idrow is null then null
         else row_number() over (partition by affected, incidents, field, owner, idrow order by insert_date desc)
       end as counter_row,
       *
  from FILTER_INITIAL
)
select *
  from LAST_DATA
 where (counter_field = 1 and counter_row is null)
    or (counter_field = 1 and counter_row = 1)
```

However, in Oracle, it is not working correctly for me, telling me that I am missing an expression starting with `* from FILTRADO_INICIAL`. Does anyone know what the problem must be?

Thank you so much.

I hope someone can know the solution :)

Comment: Please edit your question to that the SQL is readable. Tip: indenting 4 spaces will give you code layout

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you need to *qualify* the asterisk with table name or alias:

```
              END AS contador_row,
              FILTRADO_INICIAL.*                               --> here
         FROM FILTRADO_INICIAL)
```

Complete code:

```
WITH
   FILTRADO_INICIAL
   AS
      (SELECT *
         FROM SUREM.tabs_values tv
        WHERE     tv.afectado = 1
              AND tv.incidentes = 1
              AND tv.tab = 12),
   LAST_DATA
   AS
      (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN idrow IS NULL
                 THEN
                    ROW_NUMBER ()
                       OVER (PARTITION BY afectado,
                                          incidentes,
                                          field,
                                          owner
                             ORDER BY insert_date DESC)
                 ELSE
                    1
              END AS contador_field,
              CASE
                 WHEN idrow IS NULL
                 THEN
                    NULL
                 ELSE
                    ROW_NUMBER ()
                       OVER (PARTITION BY afectado,
                                          incidentes,
                                          field,
                                          owner,
                                          idrow
                             ORDER BY insert_date DESC)
              END AS contador_row,
              FILTRADO_INICIAL.*                               --> here
         FROM FILTRADO_INICIAL)
SELECT *
  FROM LAST_DATA
 WHERE    (    contador_field = 1
           AND contador_row IS NULL)
       OR (    contador_field = 1
           AND contador_row = 1)
```